# Do Slideshare APIs still working? I can not make GET request to this

Tags: api

Currently, I want to make a sample API call for Slideshow Search, so I do step by step as the instruction from Slideshare [document](https://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation):

- Get API Keys and Shared Secret
- Get current [timestamps](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)
  (I wonder that should I get the Current Unix Timestamp or make another timestamp with my time zone? )
- Get SHA1 hash of Shared Secret + Timestamps
- Make a API call to this url:

https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/search_slideshows?q=animal&api_key=UCaTqZno&ts=1538496600&hash=C447AE64DC837DE22F16543A64F638F58E760CC9

But then I got Failed API validation Error.

Did I do something wrong? Or the Slideshare server is not working anymore?